# Python can't concatenate lists because they include nonetype elements

Tags: python, list, concatenation, quicksort, nonetype

I'm trying to implement quicksort in python. Here is my code:

```
def quicksort(numbers):
    less = []
    is_pivot = []
    larger = []

    if len(numbers) > 1:
        pivot = numbers[0]
        for x in numbers:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x == pivot:
                is_pivot.append(x)
            else:
                larger.append(x)
        sorted_list = quicksort(less) + is_pivot + quicksort(larger)
        print(sorted_list)
    else:
        print(numbers)
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
  File "sortingalgorithms.py", line 101, in <module>
quicksort(numbers)
File "sortingalgorithms.py", line 66, in quicksort
sorted_list = quicksort(less) + is_pivot + quicksort(larger)
File "sortingalgorithms.py", line 66, in quicksort
sorted_list = quicksort(less) + is_pivot + quicksort(larger)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

When I try to print the lists without concatenating them I get the following output for a list with the numbers 3,2,1

```
[1.0]
[]
[None, [2.0], None]
[]
[None, [3.0], None]
```

Where are the nonetype elements coming from, and how can I solve my issue? Thanks

Comment: You have no `return` statement, so your function returns `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem is coming solely from this line:

```
sorted_list = quicksort(less) + is_pivot + quicksort(larger)
```

Think carefully here, your function is not returning anything. Therefore, `quicksort(less)` and `quicksort(larger)` will return `None`.

Therefore, `sorted_list` becomes `[None, [2.0], None]`

Basically, replace the `print` lines with `return` statements and then print outside of the function.

Here is my solution:

```
def quicksort(numbers):
    less = []
    is_pivot = []
    larger = []

    if len(numbers) > 1:
        pivot = numbers[0]
        for x in numbers:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x == pivot:
                is_pivot.append(x)
            else:
                larger.append(x)
        sorted_list = quicksort(less) + is_pivot + quicksort(larger)
        return sorted_list # Replaced print statement here.
    else:
        return numbers  # Replaced print statement here.

print(quicksort([1,3,4,2,5,0]))
```

Comment: So as I understand it, I must change my line that is supposed to print the sorted list to a return statement instead? because I tried just that, and I get the same error. So now instead of print(sorted_list) I'm doing return sorted_list

Comment: Please see the full solution I just added. I replaced all print statements (including the base case found in the `else` statement) with return statements and it is working fine.

Comment: Ah, the issue was that I didn't do a return statement in the else statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `None` at the moment you need to return something like this:

```
def quickSort(numbers):
    less = []
    is_pivot = []
    larger = []

    if len(numbers) <= 1:
        return numbers
    else:
        pivot = numbers[0]
        for x in numbers:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            elif x > pivot:
                larger.append(x)
            else:
                is_pivot.append(x)
        less = quickSort(less)
        larger = quickSort(larger)
        return less + is_pivot + larger

test = [87, 3, 42, -893, -5, 107, 3, 27, 0]
test = quickSort(test)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
[-893, -5, 0, 3, 3, 27, 42, 87, 107]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EizN/1)

Comment: downvoted because you didn't actually _explained_ what was wrong.